# Keras ValueError: Error when checking input: expected anchor_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (18, 1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, dimensions, siamese-network

I have a dimension problems when trying to create a siamese network

This is the code I used as my custom loss function and for my model

```
input_shape = (1, 18)
embedding_size = 25

class CosineLossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CosineLossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def cosine_loss(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)
        y = K.l2_normalize(y, axis=-1)
        return -K.mean(x * y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        loss = self.cosine_loss(inputs)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return loss

def build_network(input_shape, embeddingsize):
    model = models.Sequential()
    print(input_shape)
    model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(embeddingsize, activation=None))
    return model

def build_model(input_shape, network):
    '''
    Define the Keras Model for training 
        Input : 
            input_shape : shape of input images
            network : Neural network to train outputing embeddings

    '''
    print(input_shape)
     # Define the tensors for the three input images
    train_input = Input(input_shape, name="train_input")
    anchor_input = Input(input_shape, name="anchor_input")

    # Generate the encodings (feature vectors) for the three images
    encoded_t = network(train_input)
    encoded_a = network(anchor_input)

    # cosine distance
    loss_layer = CosineLossLayer(name='Cosine_loss_layer')([encoded_a,encoded_t])

    # Connect the inputs with the outputs
    network_train = models.Model(inputs=[anchor_input,train_input],outputs=loss_layer)

    # return the model
    return network_train
```

When I compile and summarise it like that:

```
network = build_network(input_shape,embeddingsize=25)
network_train = build_model(input_shape,network)
optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.00006)
network_train.compile(loss=None,optimizer=optimizer)
network_train.summary()
```

I obtain

```
(18, 1)
(18, 1)
WARNING:tensorflow:Output Cosine_loss_layer missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to Cosine_loss_layer.
Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
anchor_input (InputLayer)       [(None, 18, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
train_input (InputLayer)        [(None, 18, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_4 (Sequential)       (None, 25)           33113       train_input[0][0]                
                                                                 anchor_input[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Cosine_loss_layer (CosineLossLa (None, 1)            0           sequential_4[2][0]               
                                                                 sequential_4[1][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 33,113
Trainable params: 33,113
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Which is totally what I want.

But then when I try to fit my model using my data I can't due do dimension errors:

```
network_train.fit(x =[train_1, train_2], y=[X_tr1, X_tr2], epochs = 50, batch_size = 1)

    .
    .
    .
opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    571                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    572                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 573                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    574         if not check_batch_axis:
    575           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected anchor_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (91965, 18)
```

When looking up online I don't understand what happens here and why my network is expecting 3 dimensions can someone explain it please ?

Comment: `input_shape = (1, 18)` with this line you are  telling your model that one input has the shape (1, 18). The input shape of your model however is `None`, 18, 1. The none is there bc. you don't have to specify how much samples and stuff.
Im pretty sure your code will work fine if you switch our input shape to `(None, 18)`

Comment: Well I understand your point but by doing that I get the error 'ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.'

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, might be that I missed the correct syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining your input shape like that : `input_shape = (1, 18)`
You are specifying that your model will take batches of 2D vectors.

So if your inputs are 1D, define it like that : `input_shape = (18,)`